# How to pass a custom subquery to SQL command in ADO.NET?

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net, sqldataadapter

I often have to construct long and difficult queries "in code". I know, that I can pass any parameters using `SqlDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add()` method. But what should I do if i need in some cases make multiple concatenations like this:

```
var subquery = ConstructSubquery(param1, paramN);
query += subquery;
```

And so on. Code analyzer in VS offers me to use parameters instead of simple string concatenation, but something like

```
dataBaseSQL.SqlDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@subquery", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = subquery;
//subquery = "WHERE param1 IN ('A', 'Z') AND param2 <> param3" (for example...)
```

does not work, of course! Queries are dynamic, subqueries are generated by special functions.
What is the best decision?

Answer (score 0):

Parameters are for values, not for statements (or pieces of statements).

`A` and `Z` are values that can be put in a parameter (let's say `@value1` and `@value2`) (and we will ignore the complexity of doing the `IN` operator using a variable number of parameters... there is an hard limit on the number of parameters in SQL Server, 2100). So for example `WHERE param1 IN (@value1, @value2)` is perfectly ok...

You can't put the whole `WHERE param1 IN (@value1, @value2)` in a parameter.

**You shouldn't/mustn't let the user write SQL statements or piece of SQL statements (so no `SELECT` or `WHERE` written by the user), it is very highly insecure, and I don't think it can really be secured.**

Even letting the user fill the name of columns to be selected can be insecure. Always ask yourself: what happens if the user writes, as the column name, for example?

```
-- DROP TABLE SomeTable --
```

And even letting the user select the column names from a "closed list" could be insecure, because 9 times out of 10 you won't check if the user manipulated the javascript of the page to write whatever he wants in the combobox/listbox (it is quite easy... press F12 on Chrome and the whole javascript of the page is in your hands).